# Есть ли универсальный способ для пропорционального уменьшения всех элементов сайта, в зависимости от разрешения экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Передо мной стоит следующая задача. Нужно чтобы при уменьшении разрешения экрана, все элементы сайта пропорционально уменьшались, как-будто ты меняешь масштаб. Есть-ли какой-либо универсальный способ проделать это, чтобы не писать адаптивную версию к каждому элементу? Все картинки указаны в пикселях.

Comment: Как человек зашедший на ваш сайт с мобильного будет читать текст, смотреть картинки и тыкать ссылки при условии, что это все будет стремиться в размере к нулю?

Comment: Проблема в том, что заказчик барин и он так просит...

Comment: Золотое правило, нельзя давать возможность заказчику даже пытаться выдвигать предложения, только принимать выдвинутые вами. Да и вообще от этого потом страдает вся ІТ сфера. Ведь если вы приходите к доктору и говорите ему, что хотите удалить свою здоровую почку, то уважающий себя доктор никогда этого недопустит, а вот программисты увы почему-то привыкли иначе

Comment: Сравнивать с доктором совсем не то. Там жизненно важный орган, как бы, а тут просто сайт. Поверьте, мы пытались много раз объяснить им как лучше, но это всё бесполезно. Также, на мобильных устройствах мы не будем делать скалирование.

Comment: «Великий театральный художник Тышлер, создавая эскизы декораций, в углу рисовал маленькую зеленую собачку. И когда кто–нибудь из приемной комиссии спрашивал: «Мне все нравится, но причем здесь эта собака?», художник со вздохом сожаления замазывал ее. На этом процесс обсуждения обычно заканчивался, работу принимали, оставляя у вопрошающего сладкий привкус плодотворной творческой дискуссии с маэстро…». Плюс всегда нужно упоминать убытки. "Наш UX дизайнер утверждает что это повысит bouncerate и вы потеряете множество платежеспособных пользователей"

Comment: Тут не пройдет такое... Насчет убытков, я только вчера про это им говорил. Просто, там люди сидят, которые даже разрешение экрана правильное настроить не могут и у них обрезаются края, а для них это принципиально важно. Я даже конкретно им говорил, что давайте приду к вам, всё настрою и покажу... Бесполезно. Я согласен, что нужно настаивать на своём и говорить "Вот так правильно", но вот они хотят так и твердо стоят на своём. А платят немалые деньги.

Comment: Если заказчику наплевать на отображение контента и все сделать без медиа запросов, то поставить скрин страницы и задать `img {max-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: auto; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не утверждаю, что метод универсальный, т.к. требует поддержки CSS3, но посмотрите в сторону свойства [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) и [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
Например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156278/how-can-i-scale-an-entire-web-page-with-css) приводится вариант его использования для увеличения до 150%:

```
body {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

С помощью CSS запроса @media можно установить требуемые значения для различных разрешений экрана, а также комбинировать их с дополнительными условиями, такими как ориентация экрана или тип устройства (более подробно об использовании @media [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) или на русском [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)):

```
@media all (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  body {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Насчет медиа запросов, так и сделал. Через js задал, что при разрешении экрана больше 1000, используется скалирование. Всё что меньше - обычное отображение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно привязать размеры к ширине окна

```css
html{
  font-size:calc(100vw/638); /* 100/ширина_для_которой_были_рассчитаны_размеры_в_пикселах */
}
body{
  font-size:16rem;
}
/* далее везде вместо px указывается rem */
div {
  width:100rem; /*100px*/
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div> При ширине окна 638 данный блок будет шириной 100 пикселей </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Заменив `vw` на `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` можно привязать все размеры к высоте окна, минимальному или максимальному из двух размеров.